# need formatted date-time from php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array containing value of full date & time:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
      (
        [name] => Jammy
        [date] => 2012-12-12 09:47:07
        [id] => 151
      )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Kathy
        [date] => 2012-12-11 09:48:43
        [id] => 152

    )
```

so if i want print like below what should i do ?
sample output:

> Jammy joined on [ Date: 12 Dec 2012 , Time: 09:48 ]

Comment: array_map is the best practice for that http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.phparray_map

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach ($arr as $value) {
   echo $value['name'].' joined on [ Date: '.date('d M Y',strtotime($value['date'])).' , Time:'.date('H:i',strtotime($value['date']));
}
```

Comment: @BhavinRana thanks to correcting me but i was editing my answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $time = new DateTime($value['date']);
    $date = $time->format('d M Y');
    $time = $time->format('H:i');

    echo $value['name'].' joined on [ Date: '.$date.' , Time:'.$time;
}
```

For more information go to this link: [The DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)